# Find indices of blocks of 0s that are continuous

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a vector and I want to find the indices of blocks of 0s that are continuous for at least 3 times.

```
y = [1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1];
```

So in this case, the blocks should be [0 0 0] from 7-9 and [0 0 0 0] from 20-23. The output should give me the indices, something like [7, 9] and [20,23], or even better, change these blocks of 0s to a single NAN to become:

```
[1 1 1 0 1 1 NAN 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 NAN 1 1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familar with matlab, but I think first translate the array to a string, then preg_match the '0 0 0 .... 0' to NAN, the translate it back to array.

Comment: @KrisRoofe That's how I would do it too.  In MATLAB, we use either `regexp` or `regexprep`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Pad the vector with `1` on each side.
2. Use `find` and `diff` to find where the vector changes from 1 to 0 (diff = -1)
3. Use `find` and `diff` to find where the vector changes from 0 to 1 (diff = 1)
4. Find the duration of each interval by subtracting the values in 3 by the values in 2 (and add 1)
5. Create a logical vector with `true` where the duration is `>= 3`, and use that vector to find the start indices (from the values found in point 2).
6. Set the value of each of the start indices to `NaN`
7. Set the value of `start indices + 1 : end indices` to `[]`.

And you're set to go!

It actually took a lot more time writing the explanation than it took to write the code. It's quite a nice exercise to learn some basic MATLAB so I'll leave it to you. Good luck!